# PIG inconsistent record counts

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera-cdh

I am running a simple load and count function as below

my_src = LOAD '<>' using PigStorage('|') AS 
(

<< scheme definition>>
);

my_count = FOREACH (GROUP my_src ALL) GENERATE COUNT(my_src);
STORE my_count INTO 'file1';

The answer I get is some 279 mil rows.

Now if I run group
my_grp  = group my_src by (key1, key2, key3 , key4);

my_grp_cnt = FOREACH (GROUP my_grp ALL) GENERATE COUNT(my_grp);

STORE my_count INTO 'file2';

The answer I get is some 572 mil rows.

My expectation was the count to stay the same of reduce.  Is there something that I am
missing here?

I am using PIG 0.12 on CDH 5

Comment: Actually, I would expect second count to be less. After grouping on key1, key2, key3 and key4, the number of rows would reduce to unique combinations of (key1,key2,key3,key4).

Are you sure the second count is greater than first count?

Comment: Ok here is what we have found out. 1) We are using count function rather than count_start. If count function finds NULL values in the first field, it completely ignores that row, no matter what the rest of the fields are. So if you are counting field4 for certain condition and if the field1 of that row is null, the row will be dropped and you will not get the desired results. We verified this by reordering fields and ensuring NOT NULL fields are the first and then Vola!! COUNT function gave a different result.

Comment: Thanks for this info! is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Not that I could find..